# Java Spring Boot Webfux (Reactive) - Export Data as .pdf

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, openpdf

I am using openPDF library to export list as pdf through HttpServletResponse. However, HttpServletResponse is not supported in Webflux, so could someone please guide me in how I would write this in a reactive way?

This is the code I used:
https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/pdf-export-example

I found an example which exports list as .csv in Webflux and tried to adapt the code to that example, but I haven't had any luck so far.. Here's the link to that example:
https://medium.com/@victortemitope95/how-to-write-and-download-a-csv-file-in-spring-webflux-5df8d817a597

Comment: please dont link to tutorials, your code is not the tutorials code. Please read the webflux documentation about what is used for requests and reponses. Do some research before you ask at stack overflow. voted to close, missing debugging details. Also please read the link how to ask a question at stack overflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Reagardless of the PDF library you are using, eventually you can convert the content to something like a `java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream`. With that you can create a `org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity` like so (using Kotlin and suspend functions in this example):

```
@GetMapping("/pdf")
suspend fun pdf(): ResponseEntity<ByteArray> {
  val pdf: ByteArrayOutputStream = // get the PDF from your library
  
  return ResponseEntity.ok()
    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "inline; filename=example.pdf")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
    .body(pdf.toByteArray())
}
```

[Here is a complete tutorial video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVLOuRnnQsw)